# Ever notice those dangerous hollow eyes staring at you?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I have two eyes and one mouth,

both my eyes are hallowed out.

My mouth won't let me talk, yet

my eyes will have you shocked.

For though air is what's inside,

I'm one reason why many died.

What am I, that causes doom?

Here's a hint, *I'm in your room.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are you referring to a plug socket?

I have two eyes and one mouth,

> A plug socket has three holes at least in some places. Up side down it looks like two eyes and a mouth

both my eyes are hallowed out.

> They are the two holes at the bottom

My mouth won't let me talk, yet
my eyes will have you shocked.

> The electric current comes out of the two holes bottom holes only not the top.

For though air is what's inside,

> Again they are holes...

I'm one reason why many died.

> Many accidents are caused by electric shocks from these appliances.

What am I, that causes doom?
Here's a hint, I'm in your room.

> It is in my room.

Comment: [Related riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4660/5373).

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer:

> An electric socket

my eyes will have you shocked.

> its speaking of literal current shock and not the feeling / emotion.

I'm one reason why many died.

What am I, that causes doom?

Here's a hint, I'm in your room.

> Electric shock is fairly common reason of death and sockets are present in our room